# docker-compose ports forwarding not working if not on localhost proxy->vpn

Tags: docker, proxy, port, vpn

I'm really unable to understand why everything works fine on the same host but ports are filtered outside the host (even on a virtual machine on the same host but in bridged mode)

```
services:
  vpn:
    build: ./openvpn
    # cap_add, security_opt, and volume required for the image to function
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
    environment:
      OPENVPN_USERNAME: 'XXXXXX'
      OPENVPN_PASSWORD: 'XXXXXXXX'
      OPENVPN_PROVIDER: 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
      OPENVPN_CONFIG: 'Amsterdam'
      SQUID_EXT_PORT: "3001"
    networks:
      - dockerproxy

    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    read_only: true
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - label:disable
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:${SQUID_EXT_PORT:-3001}:3128"
    volumes:
      - /dev/net:/dev/net:z
      - /config
  squid:
    build: ./squid
    environment:
      SQUID_VERSION: '3.5.27'
      SQUID_CACHE_DIR: '/squid/var/cache/squid'
      SQUID_LOG_DIR: '/var/log/squid'
      SQUID_USER: 'proxy'
    tty: true
    network_mode: service:vpn
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/squid/cache:/squid/var/cache/squid
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  dockerproxy:
    external:
      name: dockerproxy
```

I have checked that ports are open

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 3001
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                    NAMES
cba39f7e94dc        amsterdam_squid     "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"    9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                                      amsterdam_squid_1
2856f2bb2b7c        amsterdam_vpn       "/usr/local/bin/open…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3001->3128/tcp   amsterdam_vpn_1
```

I suspect it could be a docker daemon iptables configuration, which I have not changed since I'm not very very confident with them.

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain /* managed by anbox-bridge */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain /* managed by anbox-bridge */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps /* managed by anbox-bridge */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps /* managed by anbox-bridge */

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* managed by anbox-bridge */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* managed by anbox-bridge */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.28.0.2           tcp dpt:3128

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

does anyone more able than me find a reason why I can proxy on the same host:

```
nmap localhost -p 3001

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-10 17:06 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00023s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
3001/tcp open  nessus

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

but can't from another host

```
map 192.168.1.14 -p 3001
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-10 10:54 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.14
Host is up (0.00076s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3001/tcp filtered nessus

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.26 seconds
```

I haven't noticed this behaviour before, and I have always been able to access all my docker services on the same machine except this proxy-vpn one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the VPN container does not really know about the network where it is hosted.

In other words, in order to have this working you have to add a route in the VPN container (since it alone will be used for networking thanks to the `network_mode: service:vpn` directive) to where to send reply packets (usually the Docker host gateway). Otherwise your packets will simply be dropped, from which comes usually the `nmap filtered` state. Oddly enough the packets will not even reach your squid server, therefore there will be no logs from that part. This got me off road for a long time, but the fact that the packets are not reaching the squid server is actually what is happening, so I'm the only one to blame to have been mislead, I suppose.

An effective way to add the route that will allow your packet to come back is:

```
/sbin/ip r a "${localNet}" via "${GW}" dev "${INT}"
```

That I took from the great Docker app
https://github.com/haugene/docker-transmission-openvpn
where you can find the meaning of the variables in the script line above.